# Laravel 8 Installing Tailwind CSS ModuleBuildError:

Tags: css, npm, laravel-mix, tailwind-css, laravel-8

I am learning laravel version 8.
when trying to install tailwind CSS using the npm command.

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Here described what I did step by step
1.installed fresh laravel 8 using laravel installer.

2.run `npm install`

3.then  `npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

4.after `npx tailwindcss init`

5.and edit tailwind.config.js like this

```
    module.exports = {
    purge: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
    ],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {}
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {}
    },
    plugins: []
};
```

6.In webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
]);
```

7.import the tailwind css in app.css

```
@import "tailwind/base";
@import "tailwind/components";
@import "tailwind/utilities";
```

8.after run `npm run dev`. I have faced an error in the command line.
[image]

**Can anyone HELP me out**

Comment: Updating node.js is a possible fix.

Comment: @zonay I tried with upgrade node.js. but the issue was not it node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help with [Learn-YT](https://youtu.be/fViAF53IfDU)

He suggested editing the code [github](https://github.com/Learn-YT/tailwind2-install-in-laravel8)

the error from the css/app.css.  changed the code like this

```
@import "~tailwindcss/base.css";
@import "~tailwindcss/components.css";
@import "~tailwindcss/utilities.css";
```

after this, it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation did not help me, but this is the way I successfully installed Tailwind to Laravel 8:

1. `npm install tailwindcss`
2. Replace content of /resources/sass/app.scss with this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

3. Generate Tailwind config file using command `npx tailwind init`
4. Open the tailwind.config.js and change line `purge: [],` to:

```
    purge: [
        "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
        "./resources/**/*.js",
        "./resources/**/*.vue"
    ],
```

5. Change content of webpack.mix.js to:

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .vue()
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js")]
    });
```

Then, of course, run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`, and enjoy.

P.S.: If you ran in any case `composer require laravel/ui` and/or `php artisan ui vue --auth` after this, you will have to repeat the process since these commands will change content of your files. I advise you to run these commands before configuring Tailwind. Make sure also to first run `npm install` before all this.

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the links.